# What is wrong with this code? It gives an error

Tags: python

I'm trying to give an amount returned based on household income and the number of children

When I run it, it says:

> Traceback (most recent call last): line 24, in  main() line 5, in main print("Amount returned: ", amount(returned)) NameError: global name 'returned' is not defined >>> –

```
def main():
    income = int(input("Please enter the annual household income: "))
    children = int(input("Please enter the number of children for each applicant: "))

    print("Amount returned: ", amount(returned))


def amount (returned):
    if income >= 30000 and income < 40000 and children >= 3:
        amnt = (1000 * children)
        return amnt

    elif income >= 20000 and income < 30000 and children  >= 2:
        a = (1500 * children)
        return a

    elif income < 20000 :
        r = (2000 * children)
        return r

    else:
        return "error"

main()
```

Comment: **What** error does it give? What is it supposed to do? Don't just dump code on us, *explain what you want us to do*.

Comment: When I run it, it says: Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 24, in <module>
    main()
   line 5, in main
    print("Amount returned: ", amount(returned))
NameError: global name 'returned' is not defined
>>>

Comment: Did you define `returned`?

Comment: How is it not defined inside main?

Comment: You either need to remove `returned` or define it somewhere.
The last line of the error message also states this:
`NameError: global name 'returned' is not defined`

Comment: @user3341166 take care on you answers, and admins and moderators, please dont send -1 if you dont give a help to a new one person, I think moderator must restrict people who give less points or block questions with out give a comment or a help, and get banned if this one is a newbie that tryes to learn

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
amount(returned)
```

... you are calling the function `amount`, and you are *giving* to it the value of the variable `returned`. In your code, you haven't defined the variable `returned`, which is why you are getting the error.

The proper way to write what you're trying to do is to pass in `income` and `children` -- which become inputs to your function -- and then print what that function returns:

```
print("Amount returned: ", amount(income, children))
```

This means that you have to redefine your function to accept `income` and `children` as inputs:

```
def amount(income, children):
    ...
```

If you really need a variable named `returned`, you would set it as the result of the function:

```
returned = amount(income, children)
print("Amount returned: ", returned)
```

Comment: How would I define the variable returned? What would I define it as?

Answer (score 0):

@user3341166 I though you are learning coding, and you have concept errors, take care of your question or you will get disappointed on this site, remember on ask smart questions, I mean, read google and each time when you get an error, paste the error, but first at all, read the error, some time on that description is the solution

Your error are on definition on functions, when you define a function, you also define input vars, or none input, on your case, you need two input to pass income and children, otherwise, your function won't have any idea on what to work.

If you check your function, you are using two vars "income and children", but that var are defined out of function, you need a way to pass them to the function, then you need to create function arguments.

I hope you could understand my small intro. Good Luck

```
def main():
    income = int(input("Please enter the annual household income: "))
    children = int(input("Please enter the number of children for each applicant: "))

    print("Amount returned: ", amount(income, children))


def amount (income, children):
    if income >= 30000 and income < 40000 and children >= 3:
        amnt = (1000 * children)
        return amnt

    elif income >= 20000 and income < 30000 and children  >= 2:
        a = (1500 * children)
        return a

    elif income < 20000 :
        r = (2000 * children)
        return r

    else:
        return "error"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```